# SSS turns black when mixing with diffuse with map

Tags: texturing, materials

when I apply a SSS to my material and mix it with a diffuse which has a texture and i use the alpha of that map in the mix shader then the part of the SSS turns dark.

[image]

I kind of fixed it when I put my Image Texture with an RGB value of the SSS into a mix color set to linear light but the pinkish part is much softer that way and i want to to be more strong.

Comment: How many render samples are you using there? It looks quite grainy and the SSS doesn't work well with very low samples. Try increasing Samples and see if that helps.

Comment: I used 20 for that one. But thats not a problem. For instance the object next to those black ones looks normal and has the "fixed" shader. and there is clearly a difference between the black and the white one.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a transparent PNG and there's no color data in the transparent region, however you're sending the shaders both color *and* alpha data.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you. I used a png and it was transparent. 
I were thinking that with the mix shader and the alpha in it the sss shader will be applied to everything that is not overed from the alpha for the diffuse. 

Now i made the background white and my object looks like it should. thanks.